# What does "Not a dream will i have left" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, synonyms

I have no idea.

This is a part of classic song.

Is "Not a dream will I have left" "Not a dream / will I have left" or "Not a dream will / I have left"?

Is "will i have left" a form of future perfect's question?

http://www.lyricsfreak.com/c/carl+butler/dont+let+me+cross+over_20185290.html

Answer (score 1):

It's an alternative way of saying

> I will not have a dream left.

These are the exact same words in a different order, presumably for artistic effect. As you can see  it's a statement not a question. It's not in the future perfect, it's in the oft-called "simple future."

Comment: We call this "artistic license" ... in poems and songs we sometimes arrange the words in a non-standard order.